# An example of a category where every object is both inital object and terminal object?

Tags: category-theory

I am trying to find an example of a category for which any object is at the same time initial object and terminal object.

Until now I have not an example.

Do you know an example?

Many thanks.

Comment: The category with one object and only the identity arrow, i.e. the terminal object in the "category" of categories.

Comment: To add to Derek's comment and Noah's answer, every category with this property is of the form of Noah's construction. Moreover, every category with this property is equivalent (in the sense of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_of_categories) to the "one object, one arrow" category that Derek mentions.

Comment: Although, re-reading your question, I'm not sure we're interpreting it correctly. Do you mean a category where every object is both initial and terminal, or where some object is both initial and terminal?

Comment: @MikeHaskel, I mean "a category where every object is both initial and terminal ".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If there is exactly one arrow from a to b for all objects a,b, then every object is initial and terminal. And the converse is also true. So such categoried are exactly the complete reflexive directed graphs.